# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'flights -> 3'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this type of data

```json
"inqury" : {
  "id":1,
  "flights":
     "id":1
      "flightChild": 3
      "flightChildAge":[10, 3, 9]
}
```

I tried with reactive forms.
I got this error in console.`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'flights -> 3'`

I have missed some controls for flights. But I don't know how to resolve this.

My function is:

When I enter the no of children then, according to the no of children, the no of Input box of child age is appear. If I decrease the no of children no of input box of of age is decreasing. AND   If I increase the no of children no of input box of of age is increasing

Below functions works but sometimes It gives wrong output. The issue with reactive form formcontrols.

my.service.ts

```js
resetForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    id:[''],

    flights: this.fb.group({
      id:[''],
      flightChild: [''],
      flightChildAge: this.fb.array([]),
    }),
```

.component.ts

```js
noOfChild = 0;
noOfInfant = 0;
flightChildAges;
flightInfantAges;

async onNoOfChild(event) {
  const target = event.target.value;
   
  if (target != "") {
    if (target >= 0) {
   
      if (this.noOfChild > target) {
        for (var i = 0; i < (this.noOfChild - target); i++) {
          this.flightChildAges.pop();
            
        }
        this.noOfChild = event.target.value;
          
      } else if (this.noOfChild < target) {
        for (var i = 0; i < (target - this.noOfChild); i++) {
          this.flightChildAges.push(0);
            
        }
        this.noOfChild = event.target.value;  
      } else {
        return this.flightChildAges;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    this.flightChildAges = [];
    this.noOfChild = 0;

  }
}
```

.html file

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="flightChild" class="label">No of Children in Flight (2YRS - 17YRS)
    </label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="9" nbInput fullWidth id="flightChild" placeholder="No of Children in Flight"
                        formControlName="flightChild" 
                        (keyup)="onNoOfChild($event)"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" formControlName="flightChildAge">
  <div *ngFor="let child of flightChildAges; let i=index" >
    <label for="child-{{ i }}" class="label" >Child {{i+1}} age:</label>
    <input nbInput fullWidth id="child-{{ i }}" type="number" [formControlName]="i" [value]=child
                  min="3" max="17" required
                  (keyup)="onChildAgeChangeHandler($event, i)">
</div>
```

Anyone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: So you are trying to add controls in `flightChildAge` depending on `flightChild`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen on `flightChild` control changes and add controls accordingly inside `childAges` array.

```
  onFlightChildChanges() {
    this.noOfFlightChild.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        map((n) => (n ? n : 0)),
        tap((n) => this.addChildAgeControls(n))
      )
      .subscribe((n) => {});
  }

  private addChildAgeControls(n: number): void {
    this.flightChildAges.clear();
    if (n !== 0) {
      Array<number>(n)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_) => this.flightChildAges.push(this.fb.control(0)));
    }
  }

  get noOfFlightChild(): FormControl {
    return this.flights.get('flightChild') as FormControl;
  }

  get flights(): FormGroup {
    return this.form.get('flights') as FormGroup;
  }
```

In template iterate controls using `flightChildAgeControls`

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="flights">
    ...
    <div class="col-md-6" formArrayName="flightChildAge">
      <div *ngFor="let child of flightChildAgeControls; let i = index">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhjdhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you navnath, I want to add validation for child-age. Ex: Child's age should be 3 years to 17years. How to add  validation  for `<div *ngFor="let child of flightChildAgeControls; let i = index">
        ...
      </div>`

Comment: check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhjdhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.. Accept and upvote if answer is helpful